# Smoothing out a move up and fadeOut

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to have a `div` move up and fade out on click of a particular link. I've mostly accomplished it, but it seems to be kind of abrupt. IE: The `div` moves up, but it stops moving up before the `div` finishes fading out, no matter the duration of the `fadeOut` method. My goal is to have it fade out as it moves up, so that you never see it get to the top of it's movement, so it looks like it's being brushed away and fading out.

Here's the code:

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {

    $("#bannerText").fadeIn(2000);
    
    $(".showSites").click(function() {

      $('#bannerText').animate({
        'marginTop': "-=750px"}).fadeOut(0);

    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="bannerText">
        <h1>Welcome</h1>
        <div class="subText">
          <span>There will be more here soon, I promise. For now, <a href="#" class="showSites">see what I've done so far.</a></span>
        </div>
      </div>
```

I can publish it live it would help, because the div is centered in the middle of the screen, so the snippet doesn't do much good.

What can I do, if anything, to smooth this out?

Edit: [here it is live](http://pauljhollis.com), to get a better idea of what how it looks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to animate  css `opacity : 0` and `.animate()` callback function

```
$('#bannerText').animate({'opacity':0,'marginTop': "-=750px"} , 5000 , function(){
     $(this).fadeOut(0);
});
```

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $("#bannerText").fadeIn(2000);
  $(".showSites").click(function() {
    $('#bannerText').animate({'opacity' : 0 , 'marginTop': "-=750px"} , 7000 , function(){
       $(this).fadeOut(0);
    });
   });
});
```

```css
#bannerText{
  margin-top: 100px;
  display : block;
  opacity : 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="bannerText">
        <h1>Welcome</h1>
        <div class="subText">
          <span>There will be more here soon, I promise. For now, <a href="#" class="showSites">see what I've done so far.</a></span>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: that's close, but it still looks like the `.fadeOut()` isn't happening until the `.animate()` finishes at the top. :/

Comment: @JoshHollis yes I got that .. hold on

Comment: @JoshHollis answer updated .. check the demo you'll need to use `opacity`

Comment: Beautiful! That's exactly what I was looking for. I had tried `opacity`, but forgot to set a value in my CSS to start it at. Thanks so much!

Comment: @JoshHollis if you want to see the `opacity` working good .. you can play around the `-=750` and the animation time .. may be you'll reach to a better result :-)